# Stretch image texture to fit mesh face in Three.js

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

I'm trying to make the following in three.js:

[image: Aim]

I made the model in sketchup with some simple coloured textures and used the collader importer, the result looks like this:

[image: Start]

Now I want to dynamically load some photographs onto each of the different planes, however what I end up with is this:

[image: Error]

So as you can see, each image is loaded but they are very small and repeated across the rest of the surface.

This is how I load the textures:  (`preloadTexture()` is just a simple preloader)

```
for(i in cubeSidesArray)
{
    preloadTexture(modelThumbsArray[i]);

    var newTexture = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(modelThumbsArray[i]) } );
    cubeSidesArray[i].material = newTexture;
}
```

How do I get the textures to fill the surface?

Thanks!

**Edit - I played with the model in sketchup and managed to get it a little better, but not much!**

**Edit 2 - Still no luck, I'm starting to think building it in code from scratch would be simpler**

Comment: Sorry, I pasted into the wrong site.

Comment: Hah no worries @WestLangley, I was a bit confused there for a second!

Comment: I'm out of time, but you need to have proper UVs. See the related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952123/using-multiple-textures-on-different-faces-of-one-geometry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: I would advise you to do or next.

1 -.Import the model blender
 2 -.Export blender to threejs
 3 -.Use this method of charging.

```
AgregarModeloBlender function (geometry, materials) {
      console.log(materials);
      material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );   
      modelo3d_ = new THREE.Mesh( geometry,material );  
      escenario.add(modelo3d_);
      modelo3d_.add(camera);    
      modelo3d_.scale.set(5,5,5);   
      modelo3d_.position.set(-900,25,850);
      modelo3d_.rotation.y=Math.PI;
}
```

4 -. Subsequently trabajr with textures independently. 
Example: http://all.develoteca.com/builder/

Option 2: I would advise you to do or this: 
1 -. Create the geometric shape (vertices) to modify each of the faces of the texture. 
Example: http://develoteca.com/Panel/

Greetings.

Comment: Though I did not follow the above method, I do believe that one of the options would have been sufficient.

Comment: What I actually did was rebuild the model in 3DS Max and exported an obj, then converted that to json using the Three.js provided converter.